# How can we use genetic algorithm for curve fitting?

Tags: regression, curve-fitting, interpolation, genetic-algorithms

I want to use genetic algorithm in order to fit a curve to some data, or in other words, to estimate some equation that describes the relationship.

Suppose that I select the equation to be a polynomial of the 4th degree in this form, 
y= wx^4 + zx^3 + vx^2 + tx + B, I want to use genetic algorithm to estimate the parameters, w,z,v,t,B. After some reading I could know that minimization of the summation of squared error may work as a good fitness function or criteria. What I want to ask about is what is the first step in estimating the parameters and making generation for that?

Is it good to start with random parameters, then adjust them through generations? Is there a better point to start from rather than having a huge domain of continues random parameters?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The docs for [Eureqa](http://formulize.nutonian.com/documentation/eureqa/), a commercial genetic algorithm for curve fitting, might provide many of the answers you seek in this regard.